# How to keep my tracking pixel from hanging other peoples websites when i restart my server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I created a tracking pixel for one of my web applications.

The issue that i am having is that when a website has my tracking pixel and i restart my server, any user that has my tracking pixel on their site, their website will stay loading until my server is done restarting so it can run my javascript code.

I am currently using Heroku to host my Ruby on Rails app so every time i push an update this will happen, is there any way i can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [zero downtime deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot). Heroku calls it "Preboot".

But it can't be done for free and hobby dynos.

> Preboot is only available to apps that are using professional dyno
>   types (standard and performance). Applications using free or hobby
>   dynos do not have access to preboot.

Comment: Thanks it works! i've had a Pro dyno and never new about this!